# Is it possible to increase voltage without changing the current?

Tags: voltage, constant-current

If we have a certain power applied to a circuit, and we would only like to increase the voltage applied by large factors... can this be done? Maybe by increasing only the resistance? 
Or maybe by using a constant current source?

Comment: What kind of circuit do you have in mind?  What's the end goal?  Is this just a theoretical question, or are you trying to achieve a practical result?  At the moment, your question is unclear.

Comment: I quote. Anyway you either choose the voltage or the current, and the load chooses the other. You can impose voltage but not current, or vice versa. That's true for "normal" bipoles of course... I can't tell how your circuit looks like.

Comment: power = volts x amps. If you increase volts and keep current constant you increase power.

Comment: This is a theoretical question for understanding. Its not a certain system I want to build, I just want to understand the principles properly. Sorry for not clarifying earlier. @NickAlexeev

Comment: @VladimirCravero & Andy, I believe this its possible solely based on P = IV, by increasing power its doable, but how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If we have a certain power applied to a circuit

I assume this means that you wish to maintain that certain power supplied to the circuit

> and we would only like to increase the voltage applied by large
>   factors

then the supplied current must decrease by the same large factor *period*.  The power delivered by the source is simply the product of the source voltage and the source current:

$$p_S = v_S \cdot i_S $$

It really is that simple; if the source power is constant and the source voltage is increased, the source current must decrease proportionally.

So, the answer to your question

> Is it possible to increase voltage without changing the current?

is *no* if you wish to maintain the "certain power".

Comment: Your right! My question should state that its fine if power increases, so since it will increase yes, its seems possible to only increase voltage and make current the same.

Comment: Yet, if voltage increases at the same current, what happens to the resistance? Would it affect the current from being constant in any way?

Comment: @Key, if the circuit that is powered is equivalent to a resistor \$R\$, the source voltage and current are *not* independent, i.e., \$\frac{v_S}{i_S} = R\$ so, for example, increasing the voltage necessarily increases the current and power.

Comment: May you please clarify I am confused. First of all... can we increase voltage and have the same current? Overall increasing power. And in that case of increasing power via only voltage, what happens the resistance?

Comment: @Key, it is not at all clear to me what you're confused about or what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Can we increase voltage while current stays the same? GIVEN, that power can and will be increased? + Thank you!

Comment: @Key, in general, *no*.  For example, if you increase the voltage across a resistor, the current will not stay the same *unless* the resistance increases in such a way that the current is constant, i.e., if the load is a current source.